# Insert multiple items from a Datagrid to an Arraylist

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, arraylist

I have a `datagrid` that I want to store select columns into an `array list`.

Then I want to send the `array list` to store in a database when the user clicks `submit`.

```
Private alBackUp As New System.Collections.ArrayList()

Private Sub CancelUserUpdate()

    Dim backuplist As String = String.Empty

    For i As Integer = 0 To backuplist.Rows.Count - 1
        backuplist = dgvBackup.CurrentRow.Index

        Dim col1 As String = dgvBackup.Item("col1", i).Value
        Dim col2 As String = dgvBackup.Item("col2", i).Value
        Dim col3 As String = dgvBackup.Item("col3", i).Value
        Dim col4 As String = dgvBackup.Item("col3", i).Value

        alBackUp.Add(col1,col2,col3,col4)

    Next
End Sub
```

When the user clicks the submit button, send items to store in datebase

```
Private Sub CancelUserUpdate()
        For i As Integer = 0 To alBackUp.Rows.Count - 1                
            CancelUpdate(alBackUp)
        Next
End Sub

       Public Shared Function CancelUpdate(ByVal col1 As String, ByVal col2 As String, ByVal col3 As String, ByVal col4 As String) As DataTable

        .....
        .....
        .....

       End Function
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to store certain columns in a datagrid in a ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this line: `For i As Integer = 0 To backuplist.Rows.Count - 1` looks like it should be `For i As Integer = 0 To dgvBackup.Rows.Count - 1` since 'backuplist' is defined as a 'String' and not a 'DataGridView', but this should have been an obvious error showing in your code.

Secondly, this `backuplist = dgvBackup.CurrentRow.Index` should also be showing you an error, since `Index` is type 'Integer', and `backuplist` is declared as type `String`.

And then again you are using `alBackup` as if it's a `DataGridView` in the line here: `alBackUp.Rows.Count` but it is an `Array` so this should be 'alBackup.GetUpperBound(0)'

So the code you posted is packed full of errors, try ironing those out first before moving on to your actual logic.

Comment: Okay, if I was to start again, What would be the best way to store a datagrid into a array?

Comment: I'm not saying start again. The code you posted is not compilable for the reasons stated in my answer. You won't be able to store anything anywhere unless your program compiles.